# How to show a view for 3 seconds, and then hide it?

Tags: android, user-interface

I tried with threads, but android throws "CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.".

So how can I wait 3 seconds and then hide the view, letting the GUI responsive?

--

A Timer uses another thread either, so it will not solve..

Comment: Simple example for Splash screen in Android, userful to you:[here](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-loading-welcome-splash-spash-screen-example "spash screen example")

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Spawn a separate thread that sleeps for 3 seconds then call `runOnUiThread` to hide the view.

```
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Do some stuff
                }
            });
        }
    };
    thread.start(); //start the thread
```

Comment: A `Message` and a `Handler` would be a more Android-y way to do the same thing, particularly when it comes to UI manipulation.

Comment: it still makes the GUI unresponsible to my key press while the thread is sleeping.

Comment: oh, sorry, I see now that the spleep is outside the runOnUiThread.. But this won't work for me, becouse I will in this same method make the View visible, then sleep, and make it invisible. Got it? Like a blink. And, by the way, I can't use Toasts becouse I can show just 1 at a time.

Comment: Oh god.. what a travel.. it worked! =D just put the setVisible before the first thread starts.. XD

Comment: SystemClock.sleep(millis) is a utility function very similar to Thread.sleep(millis), but it ignores InterruptedException. Use this function for delays if you do not use Thread.interrupt(), as it will preserve the interrupted state of the thread.

Answer (score 72):

There is an easier way to do it: use [View.postDelayed(runnable, delay)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long))

```
View view = yourView;
view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }, 3000);
```

It's not very precise: may be hidden in 3.5 or 3.2 seconds, because it posts into the ui thread's message queue.

Use post() or runOnUiThread() just something as setTimeout().

Comment: I suppose it should be postDelayed and not post

Comment: +1 As its far less trouble making than using `wait` or `sleep`. But you have a typo (its `Runnable() { ... }`, and there's a `;` missing) please fix it so you may get more upvotes. Also points for mentioning `runOnUithread`. And what comes next is because i'm kinda obsessive with details, but perhaps correct the english use in some sentences? (Don't kill me please! ;) ). I'm just saying because I think this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: The syntactically correct version is: `view.postDelayed(new Runnable() { public void run() { view.setVisibility(View.GONE); } }, 3000);`

Answer (score 20):

Without the need to have a reference to a view or sleep a thread:

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // do stuff
        }
    }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 7):

I know this is a stretch, but here's an answer with coroutines if you happen to use them:

```
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        delay(3000)
        header.visibility = View.GONE
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can show your view and then hide it this way.

```
View view = yourView;
view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
new Handler().postDelayed(() ->  view.setVisibility(View.GONE), 3000);
```

Comment: Lovely man. I just wanted to dismiss a fragment and this worked out well.

``new Handler().postDelayed(() -> mWarningFragment.dismiss(), 3000);``

Comment: Glad, that helped. Please upvote if this solved your issued

Answer (score 1):

Latest Kotlin code:

```
YourView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
// removing the banner after 3 sec
YourView.postDelayed({
   YourView.visibility = View.GONE
},3000)
```

Answer (score -1):

I got Stuck in Such Kind of Problem.
So, I heard about Coroutines.
That they can do these kind of tasks without disturbing Main Thread.

lifeCycleScope.launch{
delay(2000)
binding.imageView.visibility = View.GONE
}

Comment: How is your answer, different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58337053/14291243) answer? Unnecessarily creating duplicates.