# How to hide and display a view in front of a webview depending on user input

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm currently working on a project where I use a webview packed in RelativeLayout and I placed a ImageButton in the left-bottom corner:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout_maincontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton_call"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_call" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This works just fine. The next step I was thinking of is that the button can sometimes disturb my users, when they can't see the stuff behind the button... So I tried to hide the button after a few seconds and when the user is scrolling/touching/or whatever (just some user input) I'll display it and after a few seconds the button should disappear again. Like the zoom-in and zoom-out buttons in a webview. The best way would be to use the same functionality as these zoom buttons, but I couldn't find a way to do this. I created a function based on the knowledge of [How to show a view for 3 seconds, and then hide it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247554/how-to-show-a-view-for-3-seconds-and-then-hide-it) :

```
private void startCallButtonHidingThread() {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    callButton.setVisibility(ImageButton.GONE);
                }
            });
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}
```

That works great. The next step was to display the button when user input happens, so I tried things like that:

```
relativeLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(callButton.getVisibility() == ImageButton.GONE) callButton.setVisibility(ImageButton.VISIBLE);
                startCallButtonHidingThread();
                            return false;
           }
 });
```

or that:

```
relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(callButton.getVisibility() == ImageButton.GONE) callButton.setVisibility(ImageButton.VISIBLE);
                startCallButtonHidingThread();

            }
        });
```

and the same I tried on the webview. Most of the time it works just one time and then there is no reaction at all.

So if you have any idea or a better solution, please let me know.
I really appreciate your help!

Comment: user input where?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's android restriction. Try to use handler:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what){
            case 1:{
                if(callButton.getVisibility() == ImageButton.GONE) callButton.setVisibility(ImageButton.VISIBLE);
                startCallButtonHidingThread();
            }
        }
};
```

And your listener:

```
relativeLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
            return false;
        }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, but it didn't work. When I set the TouchListener to the relativeLayout it won't work at all, but when I set the Listener to the webview it works the first time - button hides, displays and hides. But after that nothing happens.