# Main Thread does not wait for other thread in wait(5 seconds);

Tags: java, android

I am working at an android application in android studio using java.

I am creating a runnable with some parameters. Call thread function is creating a new thread and after creating this new thread I want for the main thread to wait for 4 seconds (without crashing the UI). It looked everywhere and I can't seem to get an answer for this question

```
    Runnable runnable;
    runnable = new timedVisibility(calibratePointList,0,1,ok);
    callThreadFunction(runnable);
    try {
        Thread.currentThread().wait(4000);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
```

This is the callThreadFunction:

```
    Thread t1 = new Thread(runnable);
    t1.start();
    try {
        t1.join();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error caught");
    }
```

Comment: "I want for the main thread to wait" - No you don't. If Android detects this, it will show the "App not responding. Close?" dialog.

Comment: It might be worth some basic reading up on threading in Java and Android. I can’t imagine why telling the current thread to wait four seconds in an app is a good idea. As @tkk points out, Android won’t like it...

Comment: I don't want it exatly to sleep. I want to make some UI elements appear and dissapear in a interval of 4 seconds

Comment: Your `callThreadFunction` seems useless unless for some reason you require `runnable` to be executed on a separate thread. As far as timing, waiting, blocking, etc., the entire code can be replaced with `runnable.run()`.

Comment: Could you please be more specific on what you'd like to achieve? Blocking the main thread sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: You can't make the main thread wait withtout freezing the UI, you need to have a callback and call it on the main thread instead

Comment: So not really about threading but about displaying for a time? How about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247554/how-to-show-a-view-for-3-seconds-and-then-hide-it ?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you want to have happen after four seconds, but in Android you can do it using a `Handler`:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable followUpAction = new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() { /* something to do after 4 seconds */ }
};
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 4000);
```

You don't want to have your UI thread waiting for a background thread to finish. If you want to take some action as soon as the background thread does finish, you should use a call-back scheme (passing a `Runnable` or some other interface with a method to be executed when the background thread finishes).

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท  - So I see. :)

Comment: I think this is basically what I was looking for. Though I didn't managed to make it work as intended yet. thank you

Comment: Don't forget to call `handler.removeCallbacks(followupAction)` in one of the activity teardown methods. Otherwise the `Runnable` leaks the activity and may cause a crash if it runs after `onDestroy`.

Comment: But what if I want to call this handler 2 times. I want to give runnable a new value and to call handler again but it doesn't delay anymore.

Comment: EDIT: I found out, the delayed is calculated from delta0 at compilation. so if you want the handler to wait another 4 seconds you have to do handler.postDelayed(runnable,8000);

Comment: @JUSTINIAN-IONUTPETCU - Depending on the logic involved, you may also be able to redesign your `Runnable` so that the last thing it does is reschedule itself to run again 4 seconds later. As with the issue that TKK points out regarding activity teardown, you will need to remove the callback to prevent an infinite loop that will leak your activity.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to use `sleep()` because of UI behaviors, try using `Handler`:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Write your code here
    }
}, 4000); //Timer is in ms here.
```

Anything you write in the middle, it will wait for 4 seconds or 4000ms. Anyways, it is not recommended to wait the current `Thread` for a while.

Comment: If i use thread.sleep the UI will get black for 5 seconds.I don't want that

Comment: Still don't get it why you are trying to make main thread wait, anyways, check my updated answer. Using `Handler` should help.

Comment: I think this is basically what I was looking for. Though I didn't managed to make it work as intended yet. thank you